# How does "if xx > 0then" execute but not compile?

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I've got a PL/SQL-Block which looks like this:

```
declare
    L_Count number := 10;
begin
    if L_Count > 0then
        dbms_output.put_line('l_Count > 0');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('l_Count <= 0');
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('exception occurred');
end;
```

Note the fourth line containing `0then` instead of `0 then`.

Using PL/SQL-Developer, I can execute this block as an SQL statement, which actually outputs `l_Count > 0`. Using a "Program Window" and compiling this, PL/SQL-Developer says the following error:

```
Unable to perform operation due to errors in source code
```

How can this statement execute but not compile?

Thank you for your hints!

Comment: What exactly is a "*Program Window*"?

Comment: Maybe Sql-developer uses a more strict local run parser/lexer then the rdbms itself?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you want to open a new window, PL/SQL-Dev asks for "SQL window", "Program Window", "Test window", etc. 
Using a Program window, a compile button appears (=> so this is a PL/SQL-Window). Using "SQL Window", instead of the compile button, an execute button appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is not what I would expect either. However, both the PL/SQL Developer `SQL Window` and `Command Window` modes execute this consistently with how `SQL*Plus` behaves. So, this is either:

1. Not a bug, or
2. An Oracle bug but not an Allround Automations bug.

Answer (score 1):

Execution and compilation are two separate things. The code block is an anonynous block and it cannot be compiled. However you can execute the block. Execution would show you **l_Count > 0**.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: But how can it even execute if this seems to be a syntax error?

Comment: You can't execute code that hasn't first been compiled, at some level. Even an anonymous block is compiled just before it is executed - even though it is never stored anywhere. There's something else going on here with SQL Developer.